# Database architecture - one big or many small

Tags: php, mysql, database, architecture

I writing a php + Mysql web application to store family/people information for churches. I'm I better to have 1 database and 1 install of the application for each church or design the application with 1 install and 1 database to hold all the churches that will register for the service. Assuming that hundreds of churches could use the system with potentially hundreds of people in each church. Would a mysql table with say 500,000 people be too big and thus run very slow?

Comment: It will work with just one db, but just if you fill it with the Tables of the Law.

Comment: you may want to have a look at table partitions

Answer (score 0):

No, a database is designed to support 500,000 registers efficiently, you will have to worry more with the bandwidth that hundreds of people will consume.

In fact, managing hundreds of copies of the same software is usually hard.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can handle the load, so the question now is how do you want to use the data?

If the churches are separate, do not need to interoperate and even prefer to remain completely independent, then the multi-install case may be a good fit.

On the other hand, if you want to integrate the data from the churches, then there should be one database.

Whenever thinking of doing a database, please think of how you want to use it.  So much comes down to data interoperability (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

So long as you take the time to properly design your database's schema and queries you should not have any problem until you get in the neighbourhood of tens of *millions* of records.

That said, not taking the time for proper design can cause horrid performance in a database of a couple thousand records.

All told, IMHO, either would be preferable to managing hundreds of individual databases. That sounds like an administrative *nightmare*